# Azure SignalR Javascript Negotiate "Unable to resolve ...ConnectionStringSetting"

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-function-app, azure-signalr

I started tinkering with Azure SignalR and ran into a problem with the negiotate trigger.
I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-javascript) official Microsoft guide:

Heres my Code:

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://my.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=myKey=;Version=1.0;",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "name": "req",
      "route": "negotiate"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "SignalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "hubName": "jitsi",
      "ConnectionStringSetting": "Endpoint=https://my.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=myKey;Version=1.0;",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
    context.res.body = connectionInfo;
};
```

It works fine locally (unfortunately thats where the guide ends). But if I visit the URL of the negotiate http-trigger I get "Internal Server Error 500". Logs contain following output.

```
2020-04-23T08:47:32  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds). 
2020-04-23T08:47:52.070 [Information] Executing 'Functions.jitsiNegotiate' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=2b791d95-3775-47bb-ade1-ac9005929f61)
2020-04-23T08:47:52.238 [Error] Executed 'Functions.jitsiNegotiate' (Failed, Id=2b791d95-3775-47bb-ade1-ac9005929f61)
Unable to resolve the value for property 'SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Make sure the setting exists and has a valid value.
```

As you can see in my code I did provide the `ConnectionStringSetting`.

Some People suggested it's due to lower/upper case 'C' in `ConnectionStringSetting`.
Others said to to edit local.settings.json.
None of that had any effect for me and I can't find any useful information on the issue.

EDIT 1:
I set `"hubName":"jitsi"`. With `jitsi` being the name of my SignalR Service.
As in 'jitsi.service.signalr.net'. I'm not sure if that's correct or not.
Perhaps thats part of the issue?

EDIT 2:
I tried with no value set for `ConnectionStringSetting` (so that it goes to default).
Gave me same error. I also completely deleted any content of `local.settings.json` and then re-deployed to see what would happen.
Same behaviour as before.
My guess is The service only uses the file for local usage (hence the name).
So with the `local.settings.json` being empty theres no place else where I defined the value for `AzureSignalRConnectionString`. 
I did some digging and apparently (according to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/issues/7) thread) you should define it under

'Configuration'->'Application Settings'

So I created a new setting with

name: Azure__SignalR__ConnectionString

value: myMaskedConnectionString

Which resulted in the following error:

```
The SignalR Service connection string must be set either via an 'AzureSignalRConnectionString' app setting, via an 'AzureSignalRConnectionString' environment variable, or directly in code via SignalROptions.ConnectionString or SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting.
```

Comment: `ConnectionStringSetting` value should be `AzureSignalRConnectionString`, not the string content.

Comment: Just to be clear. This is what you mean right:
`...
"hubName": "jitsi",
"ConnectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
"direction": "in"
...`

Comment: Yes, it should be the name of the app setting that contains the SignalR Service connection string,check this doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=csharp#signalrconnectioninfo

Comment: I tried that. Same error as before.
The default value seems to be "AzureSignalRConnectionString" anyway.
So I can also just omit it right?

Comment: You are testing local or on the portal?

Comment: Says in the original question. It works locally when I follow the official guide step-by-step.
But theres no further information on how to configure for non-local configuration in the portal.
I found a thread on how to do it and tested that. I edited the question to say so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212348/discussion-between-stefan-watt-and-george-chen).

Answer (score 2):

I found a resolution to this issue:

I got confused at first and thought the `local.settings.json` would serve as configuration for the live/non-local version of the function. That's not the case. It's only for local execution (could've guessed by the name of the file)

So the question remains: Where/How can I edit the required settings in the Azure Portal?

Answer:Home -> All Services -> Function-App -> MyFunctionApp ->  Platform Features -> Configuration -> Application Settings -> Create New Application Setting

name: AzureSignalRConnectionString
value MyMaskedConnectionString

Then in `function.json` like this:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "name": "req",
      "route": "negotiate"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "SignalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "hubName": "jitsi",
      "direction": "in",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

With those settings it's working for me now.